# Showing error and warnings in the source code in Qt

Tags: qt, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

I used to create computer applications in Visual C++. Now I am using Qt Creator. Visual C++ provides a shortcut (if my memory doesn't fail me, it is F4) for finding the errors and warnings step by step in the source code. In Qt Creator, I cannot find a shortcut or something else except "Compile Output" pane. It says where is the problem in the source code but I cannot easly go to the problem location in the document with a mouse click or a shortcut. Is there any method for this?

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator displays compiler errors and warnings in a clickable list in the "Build Issues" tab. On my computer, this tab displays automatically if there are any errors or warnings. I wonder why yours doesn't? I have Qt Creator 2.2.1, based on Qt 4.7.3 (32 bit).

The Build Issues shortcut key is Alt-1.

**Edite to add:**
adba's Qt Creator is behavong strangely. So I will describe how mine behaves, and we can compare.

The compiler's error messages are displayed in the Compiler Ouptut pane. Some of them are of the form:

```
<relative_path\sourcefile>:<line>:<column>: error: <errormessage>
```

For example:

```
..\..\MyProj\Sim\Main.cpp:138:1: error: 'xyz' was not declared in this scope
```

If Qt Creator sees such a line, it displays it in the Build Issues tab, like this:

```
(!) <errormessage>                                        <sourcefile> <line>
    <full_path\sourcefile>
```

Is all this happening in your Qt Creator? Or is the line number missing? Perhaps there are `#line` directives in the source?

Comment: My Qt Creator also displays them in "Build Issues" and "Compile Output" but my problem is that I cannot easly go to the erronous line in the source code by using a shortcut or a mouse click. I have to find the line by browsing with the information displayed in "Compile Output" tab.

Comment: Double-click on an error message in the Build Issues tab, and it should take you to the source line.

Comment: I double-click on error messages in the Build Issues tab, it doesn't take me to the source line. It is just expanded a bit and gives some extra information. My operating system is Ubuntu and the version of Qt Creator is 4.7.3 (32 bit).

Comment: Try double-clicking on the error icon at the start of the error message. What happens? Also, is the Build Issues pane displaying the correct path and filename?

Comment: It opens the source code document which has the issue but it doesn't go to the issue line. It locates the cursor in the place where I put it before I closed this file.

Comment: Is the Build Issues pane correctly displaying the line number (on the extreme right)?

Comment: Are you using the built-in editor? (In fact, I don't know whether it's possible to specify a non-default editor in Qt Creator. So perhaps this is a silly question.)

Comment: I don't know I just downloaded and installed it.